# How do I reload an Angular partial for testing purpose?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use the `UI Router` module in Angular (1). Typically it would look like

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var helloState = {
    name: 'hello',
    url: '/hello',
    templateUrl: 'http://www.example.com/partials/helloWorld'
  }
}
```

Is it possible to reload this partial template forcefully during development where the source code keeps changing? Data changes can be mapped using two-way binding but that is not my scenario? I saw some answers related to the latter case. Is there something like `$state.reload('state')` kind of functionality?

Is there a better way to test a partial from a development perspective?

Comment: `$state.reload()` will reload your existing state.

Comment: @PrerakSola Argument has to be supplied right? I am new to Angular. How does it know which is the "state" that has to be loaded? Do you mean the `$state` is the object referring to the exact context?

Comment: Here is the documentation for it: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statereload