# How to capture the $state object in console from an angular application for debugging purpose?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I would like to do `$state.reload()` in my angular application for debugging purpose. See this related question [how-do-i-reload-an-angular-partial-for-testing-purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490256/how-do-i-reload-an-angular-partial-for-testing-purpose.)

However, I am not able to capture the `$state` in my application which doesn't even have the `$rootScope` object exposed? I managed to get the $rootScope by doing this as shown in [how-to-access-update-rootscope-from-outside-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595460/how-to-access-update-rootscope-from-outside-angular)

```js
var $body = angular.element(document.body);
var $rootScope = $body.scope().$root;
```

And then as explained in the [Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#note-about-using-state-within-a-template)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

But this not setting anything to `$rootScope.$state` thought $rootScope is accessible now. Any help? I'm using Angular 1.3.x.

Edit: Even this doesn't work,

```js
angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    console.log("Testing");
});
```

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't event `run`?

Comment: The last snippet obviously doesn't work because of some error. If you're getting a problem, it's always desirable to provide full error message and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , otherwise problem solving becomes total guesswork. Any way, in your case `$rootScope.$state = $state` is a hack that is not necessary. It should be just `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$state')`.

Comment: Ok, I don't see a traceback related to this but there is something else that is being done which fails - can't relate it to this. But it is fine. Will debug it sometime later. I can see that `run` does a `push` so it doesn't happen synchronously maybe :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that AngularJS application was bootstrapped on `body`, it should be possible to get service instance with

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$state');
```

There is no need to expose it to scope.

Comment: Excellent. I was looking for a solution like this. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

For angular 1.5.x - 1.6.x

You need to install this https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate, after that your code should looks like this

```
angular.module("myApp").run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    'ngInject'; // this will fix dependency injection
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
});
```

Comment: I am using Angular 1.3.x in this app. So nothing can't be done inside?

Comment: You need to try, I think ngAnnotate will work with 1.3.x

Comment: Don't we have an approach without the additional module?